# Vectorized (manual) forward substitution

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am handwriting code (*I am aware that NumPy could solve this for me with `np.linalg.solve` or similar*) for solving linear systems. One of the functions I want to write is for forward substitution - that is, solving `Ly=b` for `y` where `L` is a unit lower-triangular matrix and `b` is a column vector.

I have come up with the following solution

```
def solve_forward(L, b):
    y = b.copy()
    for r in range(1, L.shape[0]):
        y[r] -= L[r, :r] @ y[:r]
    return y
```

I was wondering if it is feasible to do some kind of subtraction accumulation to remove the loop, or if this looks as "vectorized" as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of the equation `Ly=b` can be found by inverting the matrix `L` and left multiplying on both sides so you get: `y=L'b`, where `L'` is the inverse matrix of `L`. Inverting this matrix can be done with e.g. `np.linalg.inv`.

To do an inversion of the matrix without using numpy, would be tedious. However, I suspect you might be able to do this quite nicely since you have a lower triangular unit matrix.

The inverse of the lower triangular unit matrix `L`, (with `1`s also on the diagonal) can be shown to be

```
def Linv(i,j):
    if i==j:
        return 1
    elif j==i-1:
        return -1
```

There might be better ways to calculate it, but here is one way:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import circulant
L=np.tril(np.ones((4,4)))
dim=L.shape[0]
Linv=[np.concatenate([np.array([1,-1]), np.zeros(dim-2)])]
Linv=np.tril(circulant(Linv))
print(Linv)
```

Here is more info on the [circulant matrix function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.circulant.html#scipy.linalg.circulant).

Now, getting it all together:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import circulant

def L_inv(l_dim):
    Linv=[np.concatenate([np.array([1,-1]), np.zeros(l_dim-2)])]
    Linv=tril(circulant(Linv))

def solve_forward(L, b):
    y = L_inv(L.shape[0]) @ b
    return y
```

Which should work as expected.

**Edit**: The previous `toeplitz` would not work in this case. Switched it with the more appropriate `circulant`.

**Edit 2**: Only the lower triangular part of the `circulant` should be used.